# Error when renaming docker-compose service

Tags: docker-compose

I'm new to docker-compose but my intuition is that it should not matter at all how a service is named, like a variable in a programming language. Is that correct and is there some obscure bug or is there some magic in the background that I don't understand?

The following [example from the bitnami phppgadmin repository](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-phppgadmin/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) only works if the service is named exactly "postgresql":

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=bitnami
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami'
  phppgadmin:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/phppgadmin:7
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```

As soon as I rename the service to anything else, it breaks with a "login failed" in the phppgadmin interface with no further information neither on the page nor in the docker compose logs:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=bitnami
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami'
  phppgadmin:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/phppgadmin:7
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - foo
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```

I am using `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` to make sure there is no leftover container from a previous run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service name, in this case `postresql`, represents the name of the host for other Docker containers to address.  By switching the service name to `foo` you now have a container that can be addressed with that hostname.

by default `phppgadmin` looks for Postgresql to be running on a host named `postsgresql`, you can change this by passing the `DATABASE_HOST` environment variable to the `phppgadmin` container.

```yaml
phppgadmin:
  image: docker.io/bitnami/phppgadmin:7
  ports:
    - '80:8080'
    - '443:8443'
  environment:
    - DATABASE_HOST=foo  
  depends_on:
    - foo
```